# Questions about Blob anti-pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, blob, anti-patterns

I am developing a video player for our department using C++.

This video player has three core modules: Reader(for reading data packets), Processor(decode the raw data), Display Handle(draw data on the screen). They are not close-coupled classes,  which means they perform their jobs sort of independently.

However, I have a GUI module that interfaces these three modules and the client. It will retrieve the commands from user, such as pause, continue, jump to a particular location in the video clip. This GUI module will then delegate the jobs to the three modules mentioned above. 
As a result, this GUI module grows fairly big as it contains many functions that the client will interact with. Though again, I am really careful that I don't let this GUI module do any real processing tasks(they are done on the three core modules), I am afraid this GUI module becomes a God Object or "Blob" which is an anti-pattern in Object-oriented design.

This is the  sample declaration for the GUI module here:

```
class CorePlayer
{
public:
   CorePlayer();
   ~CorePlayer();

public:
   void start();
   void pause();
   void continue();
   void jumpToFrame(int frameNum);
   void toggleFullScreen();
   .........
private:
   Reader* rModule_;
   Processor* pModule_;
   DisplayHandle* dspHandle_;
}
```

There are a lot more functions in the ........ area. They are functions people need for the media player. They don't perform the real processing, they delegate jobs to the modules.

Can anybody help to clarify my concerns that this GUI module is a "Blob" using the design described?

Comment: A large class is not necessarily indicative of using a Blob anti-pattern. Sometimes you need a class with a lot of functionality. Without seeing your code or a more detailed description of your architecture, it's hard to say, though. When you say "GUI module" have you separated it into at least a view and controller?

Comment: @user1118321 I have added some sample code.It is more like a management class that manages the interface between clients and processing modules.

Comment: looks OK to me - I would however use smart pointer instead of naked Reader*

Comment: @pm100 I actually use QScopedPointer here as the whole app is based on Qt framework. Just for simplicity purpose here.

Comment: I agree with @pm100. Looks fine to me given what you've posted.

Comment: Cuz the class is getting bigger and bigger since more functions are added. So I am afraid it becomes Blob in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like a blob to me — it's just a feature-rich GUI controller for a playback module. It would become a blob though, were it stuffed with additional functions unrelated to playback, like "Settings", "Plug-in Management", etc.

Comment: If you need those settings, it's probably better to have setting handlers register themselves somewhere and delegate from the GUI manager to there with callbacks or something on a button click.

Comment: I also put the initialization and some configurations of modules inside this GUI controller at the beginning of every new playback. I do this bcz that each module might not be visible to another during rum time, but they need info from other modules somehow to initialize. Is this an appropriate thing  to do?